# Socket Connection Close Event in ActionScript

Tags: actionscript-3, sockets

Does anyone know why the Close Event is not dispatched after I disconnect my wifi connection? Or any way to determine if the connection is active.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure you need to implicately close it but I do on the close callback

```
_socket.addEventListener(Event.CLOSE, onClose);

private function onClose(e:Event):void {
  _socket.close();
}
```

You can also test during connection time to make sure it is not already connected

```
if( !_socket.connected ){
  try {
    _socket.connect(host, port);
    this.dispatchEvent( new Event( 'CONNECTING' ) );
  } catch (e:Error) {
    _socket.close();
    this.dispatchEvent( new Event( 'ERROR' ) );
  }
}
```

[EDIT]
When connection is lost to the server a connection closed event will not fire, you have to test for this if you want to reconnect.
To do this you need to set up a timer to poll the connection. The following class will continue to pole the socket and if it is found not connected it will try to reconnect.


I stripped down and removed the send functions and non-relative info.
As you can see I have a timer that poles the socket and will also time out after so many retries.
This class will try to keep your socket alive if it gets closed.
Obviously you need to assign port and host.

```
package{
  import flash.events.Event;
  import flash.events.IOErrorEvent;
  import flash.events.ProgressEvent;
  import flash.events.SecurityErrorEvent;
  import flash.events.TimerEvent;
  import flash.net.Socket;
  import flash.system.Security;
  import flash.utils.Timer;

  public class MySocket extends Socket {
    [Event(name="ERROR")]
    [Event(name="CONNECTED")]
    [Event(name="DISCONNECTED")]
    [Event(name="CONNECTING")]
    [Event(name="TIMIEDOUT")]

    private var host:String;
    private var port:Number;
    private var connectTimer:Timer;
    private var retryCount:int;

    public var err:String;

    public function MySocket(  ){
      this.retryCount = 0
      Security.allowDomain(this.host);
      Security.loadPolicyFile("xmlsocket://"+this.host+":"+this.port);
      this.addEventListener(ProgressEvent.SOCKET_DATA, this.onResponse);
      this.addEventListener(Event.CONNECT, this.onConnect);
      this.addEventListener(Event.CLOSE, this.onClose);
      this.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, this.onIOError);
      this.addEventListener(SecurityErrorEvent.SECURITY_ERROR, this.onSecurityError);
      this.dispatchEvent( new Event( 'DISCONNECTED' ) );
      this.err = '';
      this.connectTimer = new Timer( 1000 );
      this.connectTimer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, this.myConnect );
      this.connectTimer.start();
    }

    private function onResponse(e:ProgressEvent):void {
      var read:String = this.readUTFBytes(this.bytesAvailable );
      if( read.charAt(0) !='<' ){
        if( read ){
          // the server response here
        }
      }else{
        // recieved crossdomain policy do nothing
      }
    }
    public function myConnect( e:TimerEvent ):void{
      if( !this.connected ){
        try {
          this.connect(this.host, this.port);
          this.dispatchEvent( new Event( 'CONNECTING' ) );
        } catch (e:Error) {
          this.close();
          this.err = e.message;
          this.dispatchEvent( new Event( 'ERROR' ) );
        }
      }
    }
    private function onConnect(e:Event):void {
      this.retryCount = 0
      this.err = '';
      this.dispatchEvent( new Event( 'CONNECTED' ) );
    }
    private function onClose(e:Event):void {
      this.close();
      this.dispatchEvent( new Event( 'DISCONNECTED' ) );
    }
    private function onIOError(e:IOErrorEvent):void {
      ++this.retryCount;
      if( this.retryCount >= 12 ){
        this.connectTimer.stop();
        this.dispatchEvent( new Event( 'TIMIEDOUT' ) );
      }else{
        this.err = 'IO-ERROR-EVENT - ' + e.text + '\r\nAttempting to reconnect';
      }
    }
    private function onSecurityError(e:SecurityErrorEvent):void {
      this.err = 'SECURITY-ERROR - ' + e.text;
      this.dispatchEvent( new Event( 'ERROR' ) );
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: The connected property stays true after i disconnect my wifi, and the close event is not fired at all.

Comment: That's impossible. Post post your code for everything you are doing socket related.

Comment: ok i know what your issue is will update my answer with a fix for you shortly

Comment: ok posted a class for you to get an idea how to pole and test for sockets connected remember this poling is set at 1 second intervals and then the reconnection process will take a second or two

Comment: Hmm... You are doing something strange... Let assume that connection was already established, so `onConnect` was called and `this.connected` was set to `true`. And _after_ that wifi connection was shut down. `onClose` will not be called, so `this.connected` will remain `true` and `myConnect` will do nothing.

Comment: onClose does not set this.connected. this.connected is set from a response from the network adapter.

Comment: You know guys the weird thing is that when I disable my ethernet adapter, everything is fine, i get the close event from the socket. But this problem comes when I am on wifi. I already try polling but I was looking for a more "legal" way to solve this problem.

Answer (score 2):

From docs:

```
Dispatched when the server closes the socket connection.
```

Server closes the connection by sending `FIN` packet and waiting for `ACK`. As I see, you just put down your wifi, so the remote server doesn't have a chance to send `FIN`.

Comment: Understood. Is there any way to know that i got disconnected?

Comment: AFAIK, you can't. OS should close connection after some timeout, but it is platform specific

Comment: @Yuras yes there is look at my edited answer. And it is not platform specific. You need to determine connection status by poling the socket.